# json web service Get value from dynamic parameter's name

Tags: javascript, web-services

please i have this output from my json web service:

```
      {"format":"json",
       "success":true,
       "errors":[],
       "result":
       {"**206**":
         {"player_name":"stagiaire",
           "M":{
                "6480":{"score":0,"answer":"cdgvbdbgd","category_name":"cdgvbdbgd"},
                "6481":{"score":0,"answer":"cdgvbdbgd","category_name":"cdgvbdbgd"},
                "6482":{"score":0,"answer":"cdgvbdbgd","category_name":"cdgvbdbgd"},
                "6483":{"score":0,"answer":"cdgvbdbgd","category_name":"cdgvbdbgd"},
               },

          "O":{
                 ..... },
      }
     }
    }
```

What i want is to extract the value (which is now 206 but it can be another number).
I am asking for your help to achieve this goal.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the resulting object contains only a single property with this number as its name, i.e.

```
result = {
    206 : {
        ...
    }
    // no other properties here
}
```

then you can use something like:

```
var num = Object.keys(result).shift();  // "206"
```

Check the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Browser_support) for `Object.keys()` method at **MDN** and use [shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Compatibility) if needed.

Comment: thinks a lot , it worked , i would understand what shift() function is supposing to do?

Comment: @Brahim `shift` *removes the first element from an array and returns that element*. You can read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift

Answer (score 1):

If the object you look for always has a player name as value, try

```
for (var key in obj.result) if obj.result[key]["player_name") alert(key)
```

Or use jQuery

```
$.each(data.result,function(key,val) {
  alert(key);
});
```